# /Library: Operation not permitted when logged in as root user

Tags: terminal, osx, users, non-root-user

Im trying to install Jekyll on El Capitan, however I do get permissions error, as you can see below. I am logged in as a root user.

```
Linards:~ Berzins$ sudo gem install jekyll
Password:
Ignoring psych-2.0.15 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine psych --version 2.0.15
Ignoring json-1.8.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.3
Fetching: jekyll-3.1.6.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While exexcuting gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/jekyll
Linards:~ Berzins$ gem pristine psych --version 2.0.15
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
Linards:~ Berzins$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  94 Berzins  staff  3196 27 Mar 19:08 Applications
drwx------+ 34 Berzins  staff  1156 26 Jul 22:41 Desktop
drwx------+ 16 Berzins  staff   544  7 Jul 21:58 Documents
drwx------+ 12 Berzins  staff   408 23 Jul 20:58 Downloads
drwx------@ 36 Berzins  staff  1224 26 Jan  2015 Google Drive
drwx------@ 60 Berzins  staff  2040  7 Jul 21:58 Library
-rw-r--r--@  1 Berzins  staff   724  8 Nov  2014 Linards Berzins.downsizelicense
drwx------+  3 Berzins  staff   102 25 Aug  2014 Movies
drwx------+  7 Berzins  staff   238 13 Feb 22:30 Music
drwx------+ 20 Berzins  staff   680 16 Jul 21:03 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+  6 Berzins  staff   204 23 Sep  2015 Public
drwxr-xr-x   5 Berzins  staff   170  9 Apr 20:53 WebstormProjects
drwxr-xr-x   2 Berzins  staff    68 18 Nov  2015 node_modules
drwxr-xr-x   4 Berzins  staff   136 19 May 21:55 sites
drwxr-xr-x  25 Berzins  staff   850 30 Sep  2015 veltaberzina.com
drwxr-xr-x   6 Berzins  staff   204 18 Nov  2015 version_control
Linards:~ Berzins$ chmod 755 Library
Linards:~ Berzins$ sudo chmod 777 /Library
Password:
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Library: Operation not permitted
```

Any advice appreciated.

UPDATE: After suggested commands -  `sudo chflags -R nouchg /Library` and `ls -le /` and got the output:

```
Linards:~ Berzins$ ls -le /
total 61
drwxrwxr-x+ 108 root     admin  3672 26 Jul 22:53 Applications
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   62 root     wheel  2108  1 May 18:43 Library
drwxr-xr-x@   2 root     wheel    68  1 May 18:34 Network
drwxr-xr-x@   4 root     wheel   136  1 May 18:29 System
 0: group:everyone deny delete
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root     wheel    49 25 Aug  2014 User Information -> /Library/Documentation/User Information.localized
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     admin   204 20 Jun 09:20 Users
drwxrwxrwt@   5 root     admin   170 26 Jul 23:50 Volumes
 0: group:everyone deny add_file,add_subdirectory,directory_inherit,only_inherit
drwxr-xr-x@  39 root     wheel  1326 12 Mar 08:08 bin
drwxrwxr-t@   2 root     admin    68  1 May 18:34 cores
dr-xr-xr-x    3 root     wheel  4316 29 May 11:59 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root     wheel    11  1 May 18:32 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     wheel     1 23 Jul 21:03 home
-rw-r--r--@   1 root     wheel   313  2 Aug  2015 installer.failurerequests
dr-xr-xr-x    2 root     wheel     1 23 Jul 21:03 net
drwxr-xr-x@   6 root     wheel   204  1 May 18:34 private
drwxr-xr-x@  59 root     wheel  2006  1 May 18:32 sbin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 Berzins  wheel   586 25 Jul 21:46 sockets.log
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root     wheel    11  1 May 18:32 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@  12 root     wheel   308  1 May 18:43 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root     wheel    11  1 May 18:32 var -> private/var
```

Comment: did not work, got the dreaded:  `chmod: Unable to change file mode on /Library: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Alright, lemme a check - test - a bit more.

Comment: Try and test what I'm going to say, and I will check your respond tomorrow since it's 4:25 AM here. Look, for unsetting some flags or clearing ACLs, the system should be in single-user mode. To boot into Single User Mode, reboot your Mac and hold down the `⌘+S` keys simultaneously till you see white text appear on the screen. You can begin using the terminal once the boot process finishes and you see `root#` on the screen. BTW, I recommend you read chflags manual page by running `man chflags`. I'm sure there is a solution. Good Luck mate.

Comment: [Don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: Try ls `-lO` (lower case l, upper case O). That will show the flags in question.

Comment: BTW, Have you done all steps in this [article](http://davidensinger.com/2013/03/installing-jekyll/)?

Comment: did not have a chance yet, working on my PC at work :), Mac's at home. I did not have chance to see this step, you suggested: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298499/library-operation-not-permitted-when-logged-in-as-root-user?noredirect=1#comment524813_298499 I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Mate, remove the first screen shot, it's showing the library put under your home directory, it's not the hidden library which you can open by using `Finder>Click on the GO in your menu bar> Hold Option> Open Library`. The hidden library is put under root directory `/`.

Comment: BTW, you need that `chmod -R -N` option, it's protected by ACL, you don't need to unset its `sunlnk` flag. But unset if there is any `uchg` flag. BTW, you need to do it in single-user-mode, and there is no network, so you cannot download the package you want from that place. Do all needed, and then reboot. And the try downloading the package.

Comment: Hi FarazX, tred the solution you provided above  `⌘+S` it was all very compliated to understand, I did not change anyhing (i hope). I tried this solution too: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/cant-install-jekyll-error-while-executing-gem-errnoeperm Did not work. Im stuck again.

Comment: That was'n a good idea to use `csrutil disable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43123/discussion-between-farazx-and-linards-berzins).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent versions of Mac OS X have what's known as System Integrity Protection, aka "SIP", aka "Rootless". It basically makes parts of the file system read-only to *everybody*, including root. You may have bumped into that.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection

The intent is to prevent mistakes and malware from modifying your base operating system. See `/System/Library/Sandbox/rootless.conf` for a list of directories protected under SIP.

Your simplest solution is to install Jekyll under `/usr/local` instead, if you can.

Comment: In this case, I may be wrong. I just tried `ls -lOd` on a couple directories on my own computer. /usr has the "restricted" flag, which indicates that it's protected by SIP, but /Library has the "sunlnk" flag, which means "undeletable", see chflags(1)

Comment: Thank you, I disabled the System Integrity Protection, still cannot access my /Library It looks like the /Library is hidden https://s32.postimg.org/y02e3epyt/flags.png

Answer (score 2):

### Prerequisites

- Xcode (Download from Mac AppStore)
- Xcode Command-Line Tools (`sudo xcode-select --install` OR 'Preferences → Downloads → Components')
- Ruby (2 or higher for Jekyll 3)
- Python 2.7 (for Jekyll 2 and earlier)

### ACL and Immutable Flags

If after having all prerequisites installed, you couldn't download **Jekyll**, you may need to unset immutable flags or unset ACL (Access Control Lists).

For displaying the flags and ACL associated with the file, use:

```
$ ls -lOe

/* -e option is used to print ACL, and -O option to show flags */
```

For unsetting a flag, you should do: (for instace unsetting `uchg` flag which you may need to unset)

```
sudo chflags nouchg /yourDirectory
```

For removing ACL associated with a file, use:

```
chmod -RN /yourDirectory
```

After using it, you won't see the plus `+` at the end of your directory anymore. `-R` is used to change the modes of the file hierarchies rooted in the files instead of just the files themselves.

Be aware sometimes for unsetting some flags or clearing ACLs, the system should be in single-user mode. To boot into Single User Mode, reboot your Mac and hold down the `⌘+S` keys simultaneously till you see white text appear on the screen. You can begin using the terminal once the boot process finishes and you see `root#` on the screen.

Notice you do not need to unset `sunlnk` flag.

Meanwhile, default configurations will be set again after updating your OS. So no need to worry, but I recommend you read manual pages before using command.

### Last step: install Jekyll

For installing Jekyll, use:

```
sudo gem install jekyll
```

If you face any more issues, check [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/#install-with-rubygems).

Comment: Thans agian @FarazX, will have to go through steps again, as I think I did not install something correctly. Will let you know how getting on

Comment: @LinardsBerzins My pleasure mate, you can count on my help if you faced with any problem.